# Highcharts displaying Date axis from milliseconds

Tags: highcharts

How do I display the date on my x axis from a json object structured like so;

```
[
    [
        634420512000000000,
        100000
    ],
    [
        634421376000000000,
        100086
    ],
    [
        634422240000000000,
        100171
    ],
    [
        634423104000000000,
        100257
    ]
]
```

Where my date is in milliseconds. I have set my xAxis like so;

```
xAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Time'
    },
    type: 'datetime'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was returning ticks instead of milliseconds from 1/1/1970

So...

```
Dim dt1970 As DateTime = New DateTime("1970", "1", "1")
Dim d As DateTime = row("myDateFromDB")
Dim span As TimeSpan = d - dt1970

Dim milli as long = span.TotalMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts accepts three primary formats for data:

- A simple array (e.g. `[1, 2, 3]`)
- An array of arrays of x, y pairs (e.g. `[[x, y], [x2, y2]]`)
- A list of point objects

Further details on these formats can be found [in the highcharts documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series--data). However, in your case, it should be quite easy. Just do something like the following.

```
var data = []; //assume data is the array you've listed in your question

var chart = new Highcharts.chart({
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Time'
        },
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});
```